# Relinking to a modified DLL in another solution in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dll, linker, linker-errors, unresolved-external

I coded a BitPacker object that takes in various types of data and packs them to a buffer using the fewest number of bits required to store their values. I created a separate solution to make this into a DLL for reuse-ability. I was successfully able to link to it from another solution and use it. However I ran into the problem of these two function prototypes in the DLL being ambiguous when trying to pass in a long long for "data" instead of an int:

```
static __declspec(dllexport) unsigned long long UnpackBits(char *srcBuffer, long long data, unsigned int &offsetBits, const unsigned int numBits);
static __declspec(dllexport) unsigned int       UnpackBits(char *srcBuffer, int data, unsigned int &offsetBits, const unsigned int numBits);
static __declspec(dllexport) float              UnpackBits(char *srcBuffer, float data, unsigned int &offsetBits);
```

There is no problem when I'm simply passing an int. Since I can't think of a way to remove the ambiguity to support both data types I decided to modify the DLL source by commenting out the "long long" versions from the header and source files and recompiling them (both for Debug and Release). However after doing that I'm receiving linker errors for pretty much every call to that DLL now. I don't know why since I also changed the instances of where I was using a long long data member to int to make sure there was no reference to the old long long version that I commented out.

```
1>ChessGame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int __cdecl BitPacker::UnpackBits(char *,int,unsigned int &,unsigned int)" (?UnpackBits@BitPacker@@SAIPADHAAII@Z) referenced in function "public: class ChessGame * __thiscall ChessGame::LoadGame(char const *)" (?LoadGame@ChessGame@@QAEPAV1@PBD@Z)
1>Date.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int __cdecl BitPacker::UnpackBits(char *,int,unsigned int &,unsigned int)" (?UnpackBits@BitPacker@@SAIPADHAAII@Z)
1>Turn.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int __cdecl BitPacker::UnpackBits(char *,int,unsigned int &,unsigned int)" (?UnpackBits@BitPacker@@SAIPADHAAII@Z)
1>ChessGame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl BitPacker::ReadFile(char const *,char *,int)" (?ReadFile@BitPacker@@SAHPBDPADH@Z) referenced in function "public: class ChessGame * __thiscall ChessGame::LoadGame(char const *)" (?LoadGame@ChessGame@@QAEPAV1@PBD@Z)
1>ChessGame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl BitPacker::FileSize(char const *)" (?FileSize@BitPacker@@SAHPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: class ChessGame * __thiscall ChessGame::LoadGame(char const *)" (?LoadGame@ChessGame@@QAEPAV1@PBD@Z)
1>ChessGame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl BitPacker::PackBits(char *,int,unsigned int &,unsigned int)" (?PackBits@BitPacker@@SAXPADHAAII@Z) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall ChessGame::SaveGame(char const *)" (?SaveGame@ChessGame@@QAEHPBD@Z)
1>Date.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl BitPacker::PackBits(char *,int,unsigned int &,unsigned int)" (?PackBits@BitPacker@@SAXPADHAAII@Z)
1>Turn.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static void __cdecl BitPacker::PackBits(char *,int,unsigned int &,unsigned int)" (?PackBits@BitPacker@@SAXPADHAAII@Z)
1>ChessGame.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl BitPacker::CopyBits(char *,char *,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,unsigned int)" (?CopyBits@BitPacker@@SAHPAD0AAI1I@Z) referenced in function "public: int __thiscall ChessGame::SaveGame(char const *)" (?SaveGame@ChessGame@@QAEHPBD@Z)
1>Turn.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static int __cdecl BitPacker::CopyBits(char *,char *,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,unsigned int)" (?CopyBits@BitPacker@@SAHPAD0AAI1I@Z)
1>ChessGameManager.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: static bool __cdecl BitPacker::FileExists(char const *)" (?FileExists@BitPacker@@SA_NPBD@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall ChessGameManager::RenderGameMenuIcons(void)" (?RenderGameMenuIcons@ChessGameManager@@QAEXXZ)
1>C:\Users\rvandyke\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SuperChessW32_v003\Debug\SuperChessW32_v003.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

I tried cleaning the calling project, manually deleting all the object files and doing a Rebuild All but the errors remain. I'm thinking it is somehow still using an old version of the DLL header file and/or lib but don't know how or why. Is there something I need to do in my calling Solution for it to "re recognize" the new DLL?

PS - And while I'm asking anyone have any advice on the ambiguity problem? I'd like to be able to support both 32 and 64 bit data types but not sure how. I thought about simply getting rid of the int version and only having the long long version but then I worry about the possibility of data becoming truncated when catching the return type back into an int.

Comment: Scratch this post. For some reason Visual Studio removed the entries I had put into the configurations settings for Additional Dependencies. I wasn't aware that it would remove them if the referencing location was deleted? I have no idea why they dissapeared on me but I got it to compile now. Sorry for all that.

Comment: But any advice on how I can overload my function would be most helpful.